# how we can install .net framework 4.6 on linux

Tags: .net, linux

we have  to build .net application on  Linux Machine. so we have installed sdk 3.1 on Linux
When i am trying to build the app i am getting error like the reference assemblies for framework .net framework version 4.6.1 were not found.

Comment: You cannot. .NET Framework (not .NET Core) doesn't run on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using some .net framework dependent library or code inside your project which is causing the demand of .net framework.

You can run windows docker container on windows in order to run dot-net framework. [This link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#1-overview) can help you get started.

Other way is to use .net core platform independent code only to resolve the issue.